# Prove that $e^x > 1 + (1 + x)\log(1 + x), x > 0$ using power series expansion.

Tags: power-series

Prove that $e^x > 1 + (1 + x)\log(1 + x), x > 0$ using power series expansion.

I am a bit puzzled by this statement because the power series for $\log(1+x)$ only converges iff $|x|<1$. Is the problem sound? Should it be $1>x>0$?

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

Let $$f(x)=e^x-1-(x+1)\ln(1+x)$$

For $ x>0 $, $ f $ is twice differentiable at $ [0,x] $, thus by Taylor-Lagrange formula, there exists $ c\in (0,x) $ such that

$$f(x)=f(0)+xf'(0)+\frac{x^2}{2}f''(c)$$

$$=\frac{x^2}{2}\frac{(1+c)e^c-1}{1+c}$$

Comment: I take it from your answer that expanding the terms on the left and the right up to sufficient degrees is a dubious approach?

Comment: @crystal_math If you expand both LHS and RHS  terms, you will get $c_1$ and $c_2$ which make thins complcate.

Comment: But my question is how can that work for $x>1$ since $\log(1+x)$'s power series only converges for $|x|<1$? That's my only question on the post

Comment: @crystal_math We don't use pwer series until infinity, we just need second order expansion.

Answer (score 2):

We can make an estimate for $1+(1+x)\log(1+x)$ that does not rely on the power series for $\log(1+x)$, and instead use the power series for $e^x$, which is valid for $x\ge0$.

Since $\frac1{1+t}\le1$ on $[0,x]$,
$$
\begin{align}
\log(1+x)
&=\int_0^x\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t}\tag1\\
&\le x\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
(1+x)\log(1+x)-x
&=x\cdot\frac1x\int_0^x\log(1+t)\,\mathrm{d}t\tag3\\
&\le x\log\left(1+\frac1x\int_0^xt\,\mathrm{d}t\right)\tag4\\[3pt]
&=x\log(1+x/2)\tag5\\[3pt]
&\le\frac{x^2}2\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(4)$: since $\log(1+t)$ is concave, apply [Jensen's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality)
$(6)$: apply $(2)$

Therefore, by comparing to the Taylor series for $e^x$,
$$
\begin{align}
1+(1+x)\log(1+x)
&\le1+x+\frac{x^2}2\tag7\\
&\le e^x\tag8
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(7)$: apply $(6)$
$(8)$: $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}2+\text{positive terms}$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple Taylor expansions of a function, you have chosen the expansion about the origin. Consider that any Taylor expansion of $\log(1+x)$ will have the same radius of convergence of $\frac{1}{1+x}$. Well
$$\frac{1}{1 + x} = \frac{1}{1+c -(c-x)} = \Big(\frac{1}{1+c}\Big) \frac{1}{1 -(\frac{c-x}{1+c})} = \frac{1}{1+c}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Big(\frac{c-x}{1+c}\Big)^n $$
The series above converges as long as $|x-c| < |1+c|$ and $c\not=-1$. In effect this means that you can find an expansion anywhere as long as it is away from $c=-1$. In particular you have that
$$ \log(1 + x) = \log(1+c) + \frac{1}{1+c}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1}\Big(\frac{c-x}{1+c}\Big)^{n+1} $$
Since your asks about any $x>0$, you can use this approach by first fixing an $x$ and choosing an expansion to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$ f(t)=e^t-1, g(t)=(t+1)\log(t+1). $$
Just simply usig Cauchy's MVT, one has, for $x>0$
$$ \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{g(x)-g(0)}=\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)} $$
where $c\in(0,x)$. Hence
$$ \frac{e^x-1}{(x+1)\log(x+1)}=\frac{e^c}{\log(c+1)+1}. \tag1$$
Again using Cauchy's MVT, one has
$$ \frac{e^c-1}{\log(1+c)}=(c_1+1)e^{c_1}>1, c_1\in(0,c)$$
which gives
$$ e^c>\log(c+1)+1. $$
So one has
$$ e^x>1+(x+1)\log(x+1). $$

Comment: So now you've reduced this to showing $e^x\ge1+\log(1+x)$. Does that not need to be shown as well?

Comment: It is clear that $e^x>1+x$ and $x>\log(x+1)$.

Comment: I will change a little bit.

Comment: Might as well use the MVT with $\frac{e^x-1}{x-0}=\frac{e^c}{1}\ge1$ and $\frac{\log(1+x)-0}{x-0}=\frac{\frac1{1+c}}1\le1$ to make it even clearer.

Answer (score 0):

For $0<x<1$, does the following proof work?

$e^x>1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^3}{6}$ and $\log(1+x)<x-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^3}{3}$ and so,

$$1+(1+x)\log(1+x)<1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{3}$$

We observe that $$1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{3}<1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^3}{6}$$

iff

$x^3>x^4$ which is true for $x\in (0,1)$.